# Finding Vectors in cartesian form

Tags: analytic-geometry

I am stuck on this question could you please help me.

**Find,in Cartesian form, the equations of the straight line through the point with position vector (-1,2,-3) parallel to the direction given by (2,1,-2)**

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A line $L$ is uniquely specified by giving any point $P_0=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ on $L$ and any vector $u=(a,b,c)$ parallel to $L$ as follows:
$$\frac{x-x_0}{a}=\frac{y-y_0}{b}=\frac{y-y_0}{c}$$

Comment: $\large +1^{\Large \ddot\smile}$

Answer (score 1):

$$x=-1+2t\\y=2+t\\z=-3-2t$$ or simply $$(x,y,z)=(-1,2,-3)+t(2,1,-2)$$